# One producer thread, several consumers

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have one producer thread and several consumers, every consumer has: own queue with data and unique id.
I use std::map to identify each queue for thread.

```
typedef std::map<int, std::queue<Task>> TaskMap;
TaskMap inputQueue;
TaskMap outputQueue;
```

Each consumer thread  work with data in his queue, if queue is empty, thread must wait for data.
If i want to do it with only one thread, i can use std::condition_variable with std::unique_lock, but i have several consumers so i need several std::condition_variable, but i cannot save them in containers (copy/assignment are deleted).
So i use code like this

```
while(q.empty()) {
    std::cout << "waiting...\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

Where q is reference to queue.
But how can i synchronize it with better way?
Thanks in advance.
P.S. Queue will always has data, last data must say 'exit'.

Comment: Lack of copy/assignment doesn't mean you can't put things into container. Only some of the operations will be unavailable. You can still use `emplace` and `at`.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18094/boost-threads-producer-consumer-threads-with-synchronization).

Comment: _"but i have several consumers so i need several std::condition_variable"_ not true.

Comment: So how can i identify thread which i need to wake?

Comment: @user3365834 you seriuosly need a thread pool here. don't try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @user3365834, does it matter which thread processes each unit of work? Are all the consumers equal? If you don't care then you can have a single queue and a single condition_variable, and wake up any thread that is waiting for work.

Comment: Thank you all, i will try to use thread-pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invoke OOP to this task:

```
class ConcurentTaskQueue{
    std::mutex lock;
    std::condition_variable m_ConditionVariable;
    std::queue<Task> m_TaskQueue;


public:
    Task getTask(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> synchLock (lock); //NOTE: consider doing this with a while(programIsRunning){} loop
        while(m_TaskQueue.empty()){
            m_ConditionVariable.wait(synchLock);
        } 
        Task task(std::move(m_TaskQueue.front()));
        m_TaskQueue.pop();
        return task;
    }

    void addTask (Task task){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> synchLock (lock);
        m_TaskQueue.push(std::move(task));
        m_ConditionVariable.notify_one();
    }
};
```

and now simply:

```
std::map<size_t,ConcurentTaskQueue> inputQueue;
std::thread producer ([&]{
      Task task = produceTask()
      inputQueue[ID].addTask(task);
});

std::thread consumer1([&]{
      Task task = inputQueue[ID].getTask();
});


std::thread consumer2([&]{
      Task task = inputQueue[ID].getTask();
});
```

EDIT2:
use a threadpool

Comment: Your implementation is not considering spurious wakeups on `wait`, which might result in undefined behavior.

Comment: you are right, but this is only the direction, not a complete implementation

Comment: Then please include your assumptions in the answer. Broken code is worse than no code at all.

Comment: You do not solve spurious wakeups by adding atomics, you solve spurious wakeups by looping on the predicate. In this case, it should be `while (m_TaskQueue.empty())` not `if (m_TaskQueue.empty())`.

Comment: `return std::move(task);` is wrong, it prevents RVO, `return task;` can still use a move constructor but also allows RVO.

Comment: edited again. and again, this example shows how wrap a queue with synchronization objects as a one-synchronized-object. I do not guarantee that this is a production code with no error.

Answer (score 2):

Because each consumer has its own queue and there is only one producer for all consumers, it is essentially one-producer-one-consumer scenario.

In other words, you do not have a single queue shared between all consumers.

Comment: Producer make data for all consumers. In producer thread i have data and  consumer id, so i put this data in queue identified with id.

Comment: @user3365834 Still, as long as the consumers are not using the *same* queue to get their data from, it's essentially single-producer-single-consumer. The fact that there is more than one single-consumer and that your producer plays single-producer for more than one consumer does not change the fact that the threads synchronize each other in a single-producer-single-consumer fashion.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin as far as I understand the question one thread fills the queues and the many threads can consume one queue

Answer (score 1):

One `std::conditional_variable` with one `std::mutex` should be enough.

```
Task t;
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  while (q.empty())
    cond_var.wait(lock);
  t = std::move(q.front());
  q.pop_front();
}
```

and main thread will be doing

```
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  q.emplace_front(/*...*/);
  cond_var.notify_all();
}
```

Main thread will wake up all threads, but most of them will go back to sleep, since their queue is still empty.

Comment: But what about perfomance? Wake much threads is heave operation, isn't it?

Comment: So use `notify_one()` and only wake one consumer, which will take the task and work on it.

Comment: You cannot pass a `std::mutex` to `condition_variable::wait()` and this example is not exception-safe. You should not be using `mtx.lock()` and `mtx.unlock()`, use `unique_lock` instead.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you, did not noticed.

Comment: No, you've made it even worse. Do not share `unique_lock` between threads, do not call `lock()` and `unlock()` explicitly. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: Also, you're pushing work to the front, that makes it a stack (LIFO) not a queue (FIFO).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing this for research / learning but for production code, I would recommend using one of the many implementations. Implementing this correctly, efficiently and scalable is not that easy, but the problems have been solved by other people. There are many options, e.g.

- [Intel Threading Build Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)
- [Microsoft PPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd492418.aspx)
- [Apple Grand Central Dispatch.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/)

Comment: Given the horrible broken code being suggested in the answers here I would tend to agree.